# Issue with Cookie Values being read correctly - php

Tags: php, cookies

Am trying to set the path for an image to be changed according to a php variable that gets determined by reading a cookie for window.innerWidth ( which is set in the head of the file)

The problem is that the cookie is not being read correctly on the first render by the browser, i have to refresh the browser x 2 to get the correct image.

Could anybody point me in the right direction please ? is there a method in php to get the cookie to always be read correctly the first time - at present it looks like it is being cached, or something like that.

Thank you

Example here : http://markaprice.co.uk/2012dev/r-img-set/image-test-ht.php

html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script>document.cookie = "device_dimensions=" + window.innerWidth;</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/img-styles.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<?php require_once('deliver-images.php'); ?>

<img class="ri" src="<?php echo $imgPath ?>the-landscape.jpg" alt="the landscape">

<img class="ri" src="<?php echo $imgPath ?>the-landscape-b.jpg" alt="the landscape">
```

php script(deliver-images.php) is below:

```
<?php


$device_width = 0;
$imgPath='';

// Read the device viewport dimensions
    if (isset($_COOKIE['device_dimensions'])) {

        $device_width = $_COOKIE['device_dimensions'];
        echo($device_width);
    }

if ($device_width > 0) {

            // Low resolution image
      if ($device_width <= 480) {

        $imgPath = 'images/mobile/';

      } 

      // Medium resolution image
      else if ($device_width <= 1024 && $device_width > 480) {

        $imgPath = 'images/tablet/';
      }

      else {

        $imgPath = 'images/desktop/';  
      }
    } else {

    $imgPath = 'images/desktop/';   
}





?>
```

Comment: I guess first time when you visit your URL cookie is just set. After refreshing this IF statement is TRUE: if (isset($_COOKIE['device_dimensions'])) {

So set the $_COOKIE['device_dimensions'] before that IF and it should work the first time as well. Or add another IF cookie is not set then set it otherwise just read data from Cookie

Comment: The coder doesn't show where the cookie is set. So, apart from Studio Arena's advice, not much help we could give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following line of yours sets the cookie.

```
<script>document.cookie = "device_dimensions=" + window.innerWidth;</script>
```

And this php file is where you check this cookie to make the decision about from which folder you are going to serve images.

```
<?php require_once('deliver-images.php'); ?>
```

Looking at your code it seems like you are thinking it that way.

1. First your script tag run and cookie got set
2. And then your PHP who use that cookie set in previous step to do some precessing

But that's wrong PHP is processed first on the server and then that page is sent to browser and your script runs.

Conclusion : First time when you open the page your cookies were not set because the script  will run after the php code runs.

Comment: Thanks Ankit - that's helpful - yes, i was thinking that way - i can look at another way of getting to a solution now.